# How to open two dialog boxes at once in C++ MFC?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, dialog

Is it possible to open more dialog boxes at the same time in C++ MFC, when I press a button? How?
(One for background: full-screen and semi-transparent, and one for a dialog box.)

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You could open the background one modally, and get it to open the foreground one. Handle the on close of the foreground one, and close the back ground one.

Comment: Actually, if the background window is just for background, they can be both modal, as long as the background window is the one that opens the foreground window.

Comment: I sense a disturbance in the force.

Comment: Don't you mean a convergence?

Comment: How could I close both of them at the same time?

Comment: How can I get the bg one to open the foreground one?